# SwiftUI - Automatically Scrolling a List with Accessibility and Voiceover

Tags: ios, swiftui, accessibility, scrollview, voiceover

I have a custom picker that is just a list with a ScrollView and a ScrollViewReader. When voiceover is off, the proxy.scrollTo action works perfectly. However, because the list is too long to fit on the screen and requires the user to scroll, iOS is taking over the scrolling action and thus the scrollTo no longer works. In fact, it starts scrolling, then scrolls in reverse back to the top of the view.

All I want to do is provide the same experience for our voiceover users so that the selection they have chosen is automatically scrolled to when the custom picker appears.

Here's an example:

```
@AccessibilityFocusState private var accessFocus: [ValueOptions]?
@State private var scrollToValue: String = ""

List {
    Section {
        ScrollViewReader { proxy in

            EmptyView()

            ForEach(myArray, id: \.self) { value in

                HStack {
                    Text(value)
                }
                .id(value)
                .onAppear {
                    if myValue == value {
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()) {
                            accessFocus = value
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: scrollToValue, perform: { value in
                withAnimation(.spring()) {
                    proxy.scrollTo(value, anchor: .top)
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            scrollToValue = viewModel.myValue
        }
    }
}
.listStyle(PlainListStyle())
```

This is all fine if the array only has a few entries that all fit on a single screen, but when the list is long and the user would have to scroll to see all the options, because iOS takes over the scrolling when voiceover is enabled, it starts scrolling then reverses and scrolls back to the top of the list.

UPDATE: If the selected option is on screen 1 or screen 2 of the list it actually works just fine. If it's on screen 3 or more, it's broken. Bug? Workaround?